# How can I study real -analysis class?

Tags: real-analysis

I thought I did pretty well for my first-midterm for real-analysis class, but I got 6/40. I am so frustrate myself now. I solved most problems from my textbook ,but it does not help at all. I don't know how to study for real analysis class. Is there any good way to study and practice for this class? Also, could you guys recommend any kind of book that included many exercises? I am desperate..now

Comment: Have you asked your instructor? He/she will be in the best position to answer these questions.

Comment: If you did much worse than you thought, this suggests that your problem is not so much with the real analysis class as with your mathematical background.  Are you sure you understand the structures and the level of rigour required for a mathematical proof in what I am assuming is probably a second-year or higher mathematics course?  But really I am only guessing: Bungo's comment is correct: you **must** talk to your instructor.

Comment: I did much worse than what I expected. I checked the solutions, and to me solutions similar as what I did. I think I have problem with the structures for mathematical proof. How can I study about that..?